# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{flutter.project}

Tags: java, android, flutter

I can run my app on iOS Simulator but not on Android Emulator.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16430): Process: com.fiyboz.sedil.sedil, PID: 16430
E/AndroidRuntime(16430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.fiyboz.sedil.sedil/android.app.Application}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3737)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3725)
E/AndroidRuntime(16430):    ... 11 more
```

When I want to run my app I'm facing this error and I really don't know anything to do.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem this way:

Under `<activity` you must add `android:name=".MainActivity"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file